# Confused about lodash merge in this case

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, merge, lodash, underscore.js

I understand how a simple lodash merge works but as I was playing around with it to try more complicated scenarios I got confused about how the output is being formed for instance:

```
const a = [{ h: 1, by: 2}, "sea", 24]
const k = [{ hi: 1, bye: 2}, {f: 67}]
const b = { hi: 3, ace: 3, d: 4}
console.log(_.merge( a, k, b));
```

gives

```
[{ "h": 1, "by": 2, hi: 1, bye: 2}, {f: 67}, 24]
```

I tried wrapping the "b" in an array and it changed again but I was confused about how the merging is happening here, why wasn't "sea" included? why did the object with "f" appear before "24"?

A step-by-step of how the merge happens here would be helpful.

Comment: You can simplify the example to `_.merge(['sea'], [{f: 67}]);` which is roughly equivalent to `_.merge({0:'sea'}, {0:{f: 67}});`. `24` is kept because it is the only element at index 2.

Comment: I don't follow what you mean, how is the item at index 0 of "k" merging into index 0 of "a" but then "sea" is ignored, I'm puzzled by the ordering and type of merging happening.

Comment: is isn't ignored, it's overwritten by the `0` property of the next object, eg `_.merge({a: 1}, {a: 2});` -> `{a: 2}` so `_.merge({0: 'sea'}, {0: {f: 67});` -> `{0: {f: 67}}`

Comment: So the array items are compared 1 by 1 in each position and merged for that position only? so item 0 is merged into item 0 and item 1 into item 1 and so on? is the array being converted into an object with numeric properties as you showed with `{0: 'sea'}`?

Comment: yes they are merged by index. The array isn't converted to an object, the array *is* an object with positive integer keys. ie: `_.merge( [{a:'sea'}], {0: {a:3}});` -> `[{a: 3}]`

Comment: @pilchard why doesn't "sea" get merged with `{0: {f: 67}}` somehow, the same way the objects at index 0 do? why is it overwritten in this case but in item 0 they are combined into one object? is it purely because they are the same types of item at index 0?

Answer (score 1):

`_.merge` works differently depending on whether the first parameter is an object or an array. If the first parameter is an array, then it will return an array rather than an object.

It is also important to note that arrays in JavaScript are just objects with numerical properties, so `a`, `k`, and `b` can be rewritten like this:

```
const a = { 0: { h: 1, by: 2}, 1: "sea", 2: 24 }
const k = { 0: { hi: 1, bye: 2}, 1: {f: 67} }
const b = { hi: 3, ace: 3, d: 4}
```

When Lodash merges these, it gets this object:

```
{
  0: { by: 2, bye: 2, h: 1, hi: 1 },
  1: { f: 67 },
  2: 24,
  ace: 3,
  d: 4,
  hi: 3
}
```

Notice that `"sea"` has disappeared because it is treated as an array of characters and `_.merge` won't merge objects with arrays if they're nested in other things (ex: `_.merge([1, 2], {2: 3})` works, but not `_.merge([[1, 2]], [{2: 3}])`). So, Lodash keeps the last thing merged instead, which was the object. (Note: this is not the case when a string is passed as a parameter directly to `_.merge`, in that case, the string will be treated as an array of characters)

But remember I said Lodash would return an array, not an object. Arrays only have numerical keys, so everything that isn't a numerical key is thrown out, leaving you with the result:

```
[{ "h": 1, "by": 2, hi: 1, bye: 2}, {f: 67}, 24]
```

Also: thanks to [pilchard](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13762301/pilchard) for help with the explanation in the comments.

**Bonus**: When I said "everything that isn't a numerical key is thrown out", that wasn't technically true. Non-numerical properties are still there, but they just won't be printed or iterated over because the Array type doesn't bother with keys that aren't numerical. Check this out for example:

```js
const a = [{ h: 1, by: 2}, "sea", 24]
const k = [{ hi: 1, bye: 2}, {f: 67}]
const b = { hi: 3, ace: 3, d: 4}

const res = _.merge( a, k, b);
console.log(res)      // 'ace' is not in the result...
console.log(res.ace)  // ...but it shows up here. Spooky
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.21/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

However, for all intents and purposes, this part doesn't really matter.

Comment: the primitive situation is curious because `_.merge('sea', {a: 3});` -> `'sea'`

Comment: @pilchard In that case, Lodash sees `'sea'` as an array for some reason and indexes it for each character (try doing `_.merge({a: 3},  'sea');` to see the other way around). I think it treats strings differently when they are parameters, rather than inside an object/array, because of Lodash internals.

Comment: The order changes the returned type. My first example returns a `String` object whereas reversing the order returns an Object spreading the string (they are iterable afterall).

Comment: @pilchard I've updated my answer with what I think is a clearer explanation. Thanks for the help.

Comment: "and _.merge won't merge objects with arrays if they're nested in other things" - I didn't understand this bit, it doesn't seem clear.

Comment: Why did you order the properties this way `0: { by: 2, bye: 2, h: 1, hi: 1 },` I didn't see lodash do that alphabetically?

Comment: @pilchard interestingly if both arguments are strings then it is keeping the first one, that seems odd as I thought the 2nd would replace it.

Comment: @jobe The ordering of the properties doesn't really matter because it is an object. I just chose alphabetical because it looks a bit nicer.

Comment: @MichaelM. thanks it made me wonder on my output that I was getting.

Comment: @MichaelM. can you clarify the point I made in my first comment, it confuses the answer for me as I don't understand it.

Comment: out of curiosity, any idea why with 2 strings being passed in, only the first is returned?

Comment: @jobe Regarding your first comment, `_.merge` will merge arrays and objects if directly passed to the function, like `_.merge([1, 2], {2: 3})`, but not if they're nested in other things, like `_.merge([[1, 2]], [{2: 3}])`. I've updated my answer with this example. Regarding the two strings, I think it is because strings and arrays are different types (so Lodash doesn't treat it like an array, even though strings can still be indexed like arrays). Compare these two outputs: `_.merge('abc', {3: 'd'})` and `_.merge(['a', 'b', 'c'], {3: 'd'})`.

Comment: @MichaelM. `_.merge([[1, 2]], [{2: 3}])` this merge did work ok for me and I got this result - `[[1,2,3]]`, not sure what you meant when you said it wouldn't? did you mean a specific type of result?

Comment: It is worth mentioning in this context that Lodash's unittests are chock full of special corner cases that somebody, for some reason, believed should be treated differently. If you think about it, the current question is an example of this as well; how arrays and plain objects will be merged depends on whether they are top-level values or not.